# Spring MVC 4 + Tomcat 7, How to implement HTTPS with JavaConfig?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, spring-mvc, https

i use Spring MVC 4 and Tomcat 7 and i have created a  self-signed certificate. Spring MVC is only a  Server-Backend for REST-Services. But how can i activate and configure https with java config ? Can someone give me an example ? And i want that only my login rest service runs with https.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. HTTPS is something you configure at the container level. If you are using the Tomcat Servlet Container (as opposed to the embedded version), you would do this through XML.

Comment: Only way to do it currently based on documentation is using interceptors in XML. I really hope it is possible to get Spring Sec updated to run on Annoated/JavaConfig level for HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

On Tomcat you will have to configure an SSL connector similar to this: (more details here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

```
<Connector
       protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Then you can go ahead and set up Spring Security using JavaConfig or XML in a normal way. If using JavaConfig it you will want to require https for your form and require http for the rest, so the configuration would be similar to this:

```
http
    .authorizeUrls()
    .antMatchers("/secure/**").hasRole("USER")
    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
    .and()
    .requiresChannel()
    .antMatchers("/login").requiresSecure()
    .anyRequest().requiresInsecure()
```